# How do magento convert EAV data to Flat data?

Tags: magento

Can anyone please explain me this?

*Which classes and methods are related to updating the EAV attribute values in the flat catalog tables? 
What factors allow for attributes to be added to flat catalog tables?*

Yes I did the homework, searched on net and checked the Magento source code but unable to come with any satisfactory answer.

Thanks!